# admob wont stop adding errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hello i'm trying to add admob to my app but i keep getting the same error every time i press save

i'm using 4.3 sdk and the xml api is 18

No resource identifier found for attribute 'adSize' in package 'com.packagename.appname
No resource identifier found for attribute 'adUnitId' in package 'com.packagename.appname

i have add this to the Manifest

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

and also this

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and this is my java code and when i hover on it i get this Evaluates project setup fixes to resolve the reference to the 
 missing element 'AdRequest.Builder'

```
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView1);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

also an error in the xml file shown in the photo with this when i hover on it no resources found in package and my package name

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads‌​"

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```